# Packet forwarding

Tags: linux, networking

I want to make a program to receive a packet on one network interface do some processing and forward it to a different interface. What can be the most efficient way to do it on Linux? I want to forward the packet with minimum delay

Comment: What do you mean by 'forward'? Are you referring to packet sniffing? That is, receiving a packet headed for some other computer?

Comment: The requirement is such that the traffic coming on the incoming interface is going to be encrypted . Above mentioned application will decrypt the traffic and forward it to the other interface.

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing the wheel? Why not use IPsec, which already exists and is well-vetted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`libnetfilter_queue`](http://www.nufw.org/doc/libnetfilter_queue/group__Queue.html).

```
iptables <....> -j NFQUEUE --queue-num <queue number>
```

Then write your own program and link with [`libnetfilter_queue`](http://www.nufw.org/doc/libnetfilter_queue/group__Queue.html). After some really simple operations you will be able to use `recv` to receive packets and `nfq_set_verdict` to decide what to do with the packet.

Comment: Do you have any speed comparison that can tell me how fast this method is going to be?

Comment: @Raza Yeah, I have a comparison: it's faster than the non-existing method you're proposing.